# Creating soapUI script assertion using groovy

Tags: soap, groovy

I know that in soapUI test request and in the assertion panel, it's possible to create a script assertion with a groovy script.

What I need is to create a script assertion with a script, but not through the test request, but by a separate groovy script itself. Is it possible to create a script assertion for a soapUI request with the help of Groovy Script itself?

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the answer and here it is.

```
def stepname = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("TestRequestStepName")
def assertion = testRunner.getTestCase().getTestStepByName(stepname).addAssertion("Script Assertion")
assertion.setScriptText("hai from assertion.setScriptText.....")
```